# How to access the "ondrag" method of the following JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is how the object looks like:

[image]

[image]

And this is how I'm accessing it: `console.log(this)` (`this` outputs the `Directive` object).

How can I call the `ondrag` event of this object?

I tried this:

```
this.el('ondrag', function(event) {
  console.log(event)
})
```

But I got:

```
caught TypeError: this.el is not a function
```

What's the correct way to get access to the `ondrag` event?

Comment: Are you trying to bind a `drag` event handler to the vue component element?

Comment: Did you try `this.el.ondrag`?

Comment: ... because el is property, not a function. you assign peroperties, you call functions. `thie.el.ondrag = function(){ /* codes here */ };` would probably be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This.el returns a DOM [Element object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) which inherits from [Event arget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget).

So you can use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
this.el.addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
  //....
})
```

or, as "mrahhal" suggested in the comments, assign it:

```
this.el.ondrag = function(event) {
  // ...
}
```